# Dart get won't run

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, pubspec, dart

I am facing a problem that really isn't making any sense, a problem that started when I wanted to use the "http" and "provide" dependencies by entering them into the pubspec.yaml file.

[image: pubspec.yaml]

pub get won't run due to the dart version being lower than 2.16.1 even though when I run `dart --version` it informs me that I do have the latest dart version (2.16.1).

[image: cmd results]

I tried finding answers on the internet including on the https://dart.dev/ site. I really don't know what else to do at this point, as this is for my assignment due on the 25th of March 2022. please help.

Comment: managed to solve it by deleting the old dart file and downloading a new one.

Answer (score 0):

In your `pubspec.yaml`, just above where your screenshot cuts off, there is a line that looks like this.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"
```

Update this to the following:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"
```

You updated Dart on your local machine, but you never updated your project to reflect that it should use this version (or a higher version).